# applying cipher code given as argv to userinput

Tags: c, for-loop, encryption, c-strings, function-definition

I am trying to write a function that takes in variables cipher, userinput, alphabet and outputs the replace letters. for example at execution it takes in an argument argv ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA. requests a user to input anything then switches only the letters for example input aBc should output zYx

```
// function that takes in cipher(c), userinput(u) and alphabet(a) and outputs cipher text
void cipher_text(string c, string u, string a)
{
    string result = u;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(u); i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < strlen(a); k++)
        {
            if (tolower(u[i]) == a[k])
            {
                if(islower(u[i]))
                {
                    result[i] = tolower(c[k]);
                    printf("%s   %s\n",result,c);

                }
                else
                {
                    result[i] = toupper(c[k]);

                }

            }
        }
    }
   // printf("ciphertext:  %s\n", result);
}
```

with cipher as YUKFRNLBAVMWZTEOGXHCIPJSQD
and userinput as abcd
I was expecting yukf but got qidc

Comment: Please clarify what `string` is. Are you actually coding in C++ or is this the brain-damaged CS-50 `string` typedef?

Comment: Either way, how these variables were initialized/allocated is relevant information too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of the function is this inner for loop

```
    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(a); k++)
    {
        if (tolower(u[i]) == a[k])
        {
            if(islower(u[i]))
            {
                result[i] = tolower(c[k]);
                printf("%s   %s\n",result,c);

            }
            else
            {
                result[i] = toupper(c[k]);

            }

        }
    }
```

You need to break it as soon as a letter is found in the string pointed to by the pointer `a`. Otherwise there can be a chain of changes.

Also using the function `strlen` is inefficient and redundant.

Instead of the for loop you could use standard  function `strchr`.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
string cipher_text( string c, string u, string a )
{
    for ( string p = u; *p != '\0'; p++ )
    {
        string pos = strchr( a, tolower( ( unsigned char )*p ) );

        if ( pos != NULL )
        {
            size_t i = pos - a;
            *p = islower( ( unsigned char )*p )
                     ? tolower( c[i] )
                     : c[i];
        }
    }

    return u;
}
```

Pay attention to that instead of the typedef name `string` it is better to use its underlaying type `char *`.

In this case the function can look the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * cipher_text( const char *c, char *u, const char *a )
{
    for (char *p = u; *p != '\0'; p++)
    {
        const char *pos = strchr( a, tolower( ( unsigned char )*p ) );

        if (pos != NULL)
        {
            size_t i = pos - a;
            *p = islower( ( unsigned char )*p )
                ? tolower( c[i] )
                : c[i];
        }
    }

    return u;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *c = "XYZ";
    const char *a = "abc";

    char u[] = "c_B_a";

    puts( cipher_text( c, u, a ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
z_Y_x
```

Comment: I was able to solve it by adding a break; at the end of the first if statement which prevented multiple updates thanks